# SWI Prolog: Cannot Define New Operator

Tags: prolog, operators

I'm using SWI-Prolog version 7.6.4 on Arch Linux.

I have this database of facts:

```
female(mary). female(liz). female(mia). female(tina). female(ann). female(sue).
male(mike). male(jack). male(fred). male(tom). male(joe). male(jim).
parent(mary, mia). parent(mary, fred). parent(mary, tina).
parent(mike, mia). parent(mike, fred). parent(mike, tina).
parent(liz, tom). parent(liz, joe).
parent(jack, tom). parent(jack, joe).
parent(mia, ann).
parent(tina, sue). parent(tina, jim).
parent(tom, sue). parent(tom, jim).
```

And I defined the `mother` predicate as follows:

```
mother(M, C) :- parent(M, C), female(M).
```

The predicate works as intended:

```
?- mother(liz, tom).
true .

?- mother(liz, fred).
false.
```

Now I like to define an operator to be used like `liz mother tom` with a relatively low precedence, which I do like this:

```
op(1111, xfx, mother).
```

This gives me an error on that exact line:

```
ERROR: /home/user/prolog/family.pl:13:
       No permission to modify static procedure `op/3'
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

As requested, here's the full file in one listing:

```
female(mary). female(liz). female(mia). female(tina). female(ann). female(sue).
male(mike). male(jack). male(fred). male(tom). male(joe). male(jim).
parent(mary, mia). parent(mary, fred). parent(mary, tina).
parent(mike, mia). parent(mike, fred). parent(mike, tina).
parent(liz, tom). parent(liz, joe).
parent(jack, tom). parent(jack, joe).
parent(mia, ann).
parent(tina, sue). parent(tina, jim).
parent(tom, sue). parent(tom, jim).

mother(M, C) :- parent(M, C), female(M).
op(1111, xfx, mother).
```

Comment: Can you share the full file (or at least parts of the file that trigger this exception?). Perhaps the order, spacing, etc. causes this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sure, see above

Comment: `op/3` is a directive. Did you write `:-` in front of it? `:- op(1111, xfx, mother).` The SWI Prolog documentation, unfortunately, is not clear on this point.

Comment: Avoid such operators, they will only hinder you learning the language

Comment: @lurker Thanks, it works now!

Comment: @false I'll take that advice with me for my further journey, but as you could imagine, this is homework, and the professor wants me to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @lurker described it in the comments, `op/3` is a directive. It works like this:

```
:- op(1111, xfx, mother).
```

Comment: thank you @patrick-bucher being new to Prolog this was not obvious from the documentation, but keeping this in mind will help a lot going forward